# Vanilla Javascript - How can I use mouseup and mousedown on the same button to change and revert a css class value?

Tags: javascript, events, event-listener, mousedown, mouseup

I'm a beginner learning to work with vanilla javascript. I have been searching for 2 days, and posting questions in a couple of javascript facebook groups since last night, and I haven't found a solution yet. Maybe I'm not asking the question correctly in my search, but I'm just stuck. If, for some reason, I am bringing up a question that has been answered, I apologize. In my defense, being a beginner sometimes means we are not sure exactly how to search for the answers.
Moving on...

I am trying to figure out how to use 2 eventListeners for the same button to change a css property value. I want `function1` to run on `mousedown` and `function2` to run on `mouseup`. I think my problem is occurring with the `(event)` parameter. Is there a way to make sure the event parameter in `function1` is targeting only the event for `mousedown`? Then point the event in `function2` to use the event for `mouseup`?
This is what I have so far...
html

```
<button class="my-btn">My button</button>
<div class="my-class">
some content
</div>
```

Javascript

```
let myBtn = document.querySelector('.my-btn');
let myClass = document.querySelector('.my-class');
myBtn.addEventListener('mousedown', function1);
myBtn.addEventListener('mouseup', function2);

function function1(event){
    myClass.style.bottom = "-16em";
}

function function2(event){
    myClass.style.bottom = "0";
}
```

Comment: If you are asking why nothing happens on mouseup, it might be due to a position change of the button itself. Mousedown function changes position of the button, so mouseup can't catch up with new position of the button. What would you like to accomplish exactly?

Comment: The class I'm changing is not applied to the button. It is applied to a div. I guess I need to add the html so you can see more what's going on. I will edit the code.

Comment: Yes, please add html code.

Comment: Ok, I have added a simple version of the html.

Comment: The example code you added does change the position of the div on mouseup and mousedown. What is the result you are looking for?

Comment: It is not working here:
https://codepen.io/chisao101/pen/MWyxPvo

Answer (score 0):

Good that you have started to work on Js.

I have created a playground which changes the background color on mouseup and mousedown event. Please visit the below link for the same.

https://jsfiddle.net/kqydbwhL/

Also, I feel like in your code.

```
myBtn.addEventListener('mousedown', function1);
myBtn.addEventListener('mouseup', function2);
```

`myBtn` should be replaced with `myClass` because you are storing the element into `myClass` but while listening to the events you are targeting `myBtn` which is `undefined`.

Thanks.

---

I think you updated your code snippet in the problem description.
Here is the new playground url having those changes.

https://jsfiddle.net/6pzhjvfL/17/

Comment: This is very close to what I'm trying to achieve. The only difference is, I am using a button for the click, and I want the class value to change on a div. I have edited the question to include a basic version of the html I am using. Sorry for the confusion, and thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your pen, it seems that position property should be set differently in `my-class`. Bottom property does not work with static position, which is a default position of all elements.

Maybe you can learn more about bottom property [here](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/bottom/).

Take a look at this [example](https://codepen.io/tonkec/pen/NWNJOaN). I added `position:relative` to `my-class`.  Try it with `position:absolute` if that is the result you wanted.

Comment: This is the problem with being a beginner...
I'm doing my best to provide the right code without putting my entire project here, and unfortunately I forget that all these things are related. I have edited the codepen to reflect what is in my original project and it does work there. But it is still not working in my  original project. I think I need to review it for the thousandth time. lol
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the responses here, it was pointed out to me that my code actually works the way I want it to. So I went back to my original project to review. I discovered that I had `function2` nested inside `function1' which was not intended. A misplaced curly bracket way down at the bottom of my file, completely out of sight, was the problem. I wasted 2 days looking for an answer to a problem that ended up being a syntax error of my own doing.

Thank you all for your help. I will be careful in the future to keep this from happening again.